# Is any of this a Fern?

Tags: identification, ferns

A couple of months ago I planted some silver fern spores. For a while nothing happened, but now I have 2 different types of plants growing in my pot, and I'm not sure if I should be removing one of them.

This is my pot:
[image: My flower pot]

As you can se there are 2 different types of plants. The first one:

[image: first plant]

And the second one:

[image: second plant]

I think that the second one is the first stage of the fern growth cycle, but I don't really know much about plants so I'm not sure.

Also, if one of them is the fern, should I be removing the other things that grow in the same pot?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**
Backside of fern:
[image: back side of fern]

More recent photos:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
Here is the same planta a couple of  months later:

[image: baby fern]

[image: baby fern]

[image: fern leaves]

[image: backside of leaves]

Comment: Welcome to biology.SE! As of now your question might be more suitable on [gardening.SE]

Comment: We need a better photo of stem, and the bottom side of the "leaves".

Comment: Where do you live?  I'm more for *Papaver* (or Papaveraceae) then fern.

Comment: I don't think the plants are ferns. I think maybe the mossy looking stuff on the soil is the beginning of ferns. I haven't grown them myself I've only been looking up info recently to see learn how to grow them and your pictures look similar. One plant looks like it might be parsley the other maybe creeping charlie but hard to tell.

Comment: I live in Mexico City, but I bought the silver fern spores in New Zealand. I'll take better pictures of the bottom of the leaves in a couple of hours.

Comment: The #1 plant looks like cilantro or flat leaf parsley.

Comment: The bottom one may actually be a fern after seeing some other photos.

Comment: I don't think it is a silver fern (they growth/unfold differently https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koru). But the form of black steam let's me think it is really a fern, and I don't see dicotyledons, but we don't have the photo on the lower parts)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I have uploaded the photos of the back of the leaf as well as a more recent photo.

Comment: How did you germinate the silver fern spores?

Comment: @TopoI still don't think it is a silver fern, but I cannot yet identify the plant. Keep the experiment going! ;-)

Comment: Hello, what's that? Could we get a close-up of the green "blob" on the left margin of the last photo, please? That *might* be the gametophyte form you are looking for. Compare https://movin2newzealand.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/new-zealand-native-plants-ponga/ (scroll about 2/3 down the site)

Comment: Just added here some more recent photos of the same plants. Anyone care to take a guess to what kind of.plant it might be

Comment: perhaps it's something like button fern (Pellaea rotundifolia)?

Comment: The 2nd plant (hairy one) is DEFINITELY a fern. Not sure what type though.

Answer (score 2):

The first one might be a type of Cilantro or a related weed. Rubbing your hands gently on the leaf and smelling it can tell you if it is so.

The second one is definitely a fern. It appears to be a variant of the Single Maiden Hair Fern. Pinpointing it could be easier when the fern is a bit more mature.

The button fern, Pellaea rotundifolia as Ben has mentioned doesn't appear to be it, but it could be something related. I have planted a couple of different variants of the Maiden Hair Fern in my garden. I will go look at it during the day and see if they are related to this one. Neither of them seem to have that hairy growth on the leaflets though.

I don't think this is the New Zealand Silver Fern. Two years ago, someone gave me a one - two year old specimen that was growing too big for their space. I have since planted it in the biggest pot I have, and at about 4 years, this guy is the biggest fern I have, with spectacular fronds, just a darling to admire. Even the young ones don't look like the beautiful fern you have.